# Initialize Maven Repository

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a new laptop (Ubuntu) and of course, my .m2 repository is empty.  When I launch Intellij 12.04, I get a lot of maven errors saying that stuff is missing.  Doing a clean/build does not resolve the problem.

However, when I run Netbeans 7.4 for the 1st time, I get a message in the status bar saying "Unpacking Index for Central Repository."

After that Intellij works.

Is there an analogous command in Intellij I can run to do that same thing as Netbeans?  That way I don't have to download and run Netbeans.

Comment: What are the errors when you build? I use IntelliJ all the time with maven and have never needed to manually index a repository in the manner you describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *Settings > [Project Settings] > Maven > Repositories* you can index a repository. But that does not fetch the repository's content. (It simply indexes the repository so IDEA knows where is can find a specific class.) It is something you should do though.

If your IDEA project was configured as a maven project, just do a force re-import [image] from the maven tool window. That will pull down all dependencies for the project. Just make sure your settings.xml file is configured properly.